# Why is the use of [var x = new T()] resolving to [T?]?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nullable, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I am using VS2022, .NET 6, C# 10, with the nullability context enabled project-wide.

```
public static ModelEnumerationAttributeProperty FromPropertyInfo (PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object value)
{
    var property = ModelEnumerationAttributeProperty.FromPropertyInfo(propertyInfo);

    property.PropertyValue = value;
    property.PropertyValueString = value?.ToString();

    return (property);
}
```

The auto-detected type of the variable `property` is resolving to the nullable type `ModelEnumerationAttributeProperty?`.

It appears to be a simple constructor call to a vanilla class. Constructors can throw exceptions but cannot return null.

[image: Snapshot]

So why is the use of [var x = new T()] automatically resolving to <T?>?

**UPDATE:*** Here is the static overload that calls a constructor:

```
public static ModelEnumerationAttributeProperty FromPropertyInfo (PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    var property = new ModelEnumerationAttributeProperty();

    property.PropertyInfo = propertyInfo;
    property.Type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
    property.Name = propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name;
    property.FullName = propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName ?? "";
    property.AssemblyQualifiedName = propertyInfo.PropertyType.AssemblyQualifiedName ?? "";

    property.PropertyName = propertyInfo.Name;

    return (property);
}
```

The compiler does not flag this overload and the return type if non-nullable. I might as well have called `var o = new object();`, and it would do the same thing.

Comment: It's not a constructor call though, but a static method call.

Comment: I don't see any `new T()` in your code. The method `ModelEnumerationAttributeProperty.FromPropertyInfo` most probably has a return type of `T?`.

Comment: It looks like you're calling a different overload of `FromPropertyInfo` that only takes `PropertyInfo`.  Can you include the code for that method as well?

Comment: Edited the question to add the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as defined by the language.

From [the documentation for `var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var):

> Important
>
> When var is used with nullable reference types enabled, it always implies a nullable reference type even if the expression type isn't
> nullable. The compiler's null state analysis protects against
> dereferencing a potential null value. If the variable is never
> assigned to an expression that maybe null, the compiler won't emit any
> warnings. If you assign the variable to an expression that might be
> null, you must test that it isn't null before dereferencing it to
> avoid any warnings.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot argue with the documentation but it does make me wonder why `var o = new object();` should resolve to `object?` as a design choice. I am sure there is a reason that escapes me at the moment. Until then, this choice seems to propagate the code base with unnecessary nullability defences when using `var`.

Comment: @RaheelKhan There's some discussion here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/53078